# Autodesk Forge Viewer, Search function doesn't work

Tags: javascript, autodesk-forge, forge

I'm trying to come up with a way to filter my model based some Revit custom parameters, here is my attempt on making an isolation based on a custom attribute from Revit

```
NOP_VIEWER.model.search("HZ4", dbids => NOP_VIEWER.isolate(dbids), console.error, ["Zone"], { searchHidden: true })
```

This returns an empty view.

Result after I run my code:

[image]

Please note that i have verified that the custom attribute is indeed loaded:

[image]

**Update:** it seem the function dose not worked when the custom attribute is coming from a linked file, I tried uploading my structure file only and it worked.
I still need to figure out a way to do this with linked rvt files.

Comment: Could you consider providing a non-confidential reproducible model to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com` for investigation? I cannot reproducible this problem from my side.

Comment: Hello @EasonKang unfortunately the model im using is confidential i will try to recreate the problem with a different model as i believe the isn't with the model but with my code

Comment: I tried this as well and got the same results. Some atributes were appearing in search, some others not. I can back-check those attributes exist in the derivative properties using NOP_VIEWER.model.getBulkProperties(id, {}, p => console.log(p)) where id is the object that has the attribute.I am filtering all dbIds and map the attributes I need using getBulkProperties to solve this issue.

Comment: Update: it seem the function dose not worked when the custom attribute is coming from a linked file, i tried uploading my structure file only and it worked. but @EasonKang can you advice how to use this function if i have linked Revit files. tq